# Getting a list of already connected bluetooth devices on Windows 10

Tags: c#, .net, bluetooth, uwp, windows-10

This question might be stupid, and maybe the first accepted answer will be one that explains why this is not an intended use-case.

Is it possible to get a list of BT devices, that are already connect to the machine?

The machine is a Win10 box and using "pure" C#/.Net would be nice, although there is also 32feet.
The BT device is **not** BTLE (low energy).

The device is already connected via the normal Windows routines and the goal would be to get some kind of status information about the device and the connection status.

Addendum: I searched a lot and most results talk about how to pair and/or connect and the different capabilities of Win7, 8 and 10 confused me quite a lot. That's why I don't want to include any code, this time :-)

I saw [Getting a list of bluetooth devices in a C# .NET framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45709457) and read through the answer and the comments. It is explicitly not about UWP but a CLI and furthermore, it doesn't seem to work. Even with 32feet, as the suggested API call to DiscoverDevicesInRange looks for devices that are in range and are in ‘discoverable mode’. Not connected yet. In the question itself it states that it should clearly work with Windows.Devices.Bluetooth, but I couldn't find anything that actually works.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting a list of bluetooth devices in a C# .NET framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45709457/getting-a-list-of-bluetooth-devices-in-a-c-sharp-net-framework)

Comment: too late.... already flagged.

Comment: It should be possible in UWP , because i've been working on Wifi API provided in UWP and in that , we can get a list of all the available access points.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/bluetoothapis/nf-bluetoothapis-bluetoothfindfirstdevice

Comment: To all: Thanks for the hints and the answer. I will try these out and report back, might take a week (holidays!) :-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can find the Paired or Connected Bluetooth device by using the [DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(String)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.enumeration.deviceinformation.findallasync#Windows_Devices_Enumeration_DeviceInformation_FindAllAsync_System_String_) method, you can specify the string to be `BluetoothDevice.GetDeviceSelectorFromPairingState(true)` or `BluetoothDevice.GetDeviceSelectorFromConnectionStatus(BluetoothConnectionStatus.Connected)` as the following code.

```
//Paired bluetooth devices
DeviceInformationCollection PairedBluetoothDevices =
       await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(BluetoothDevice.GetDeviceSelectorFromPairingState(true));
//Connected bluetooth devices
DeviceInformationCollection ConnectedBluetoothDevices =
       await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(BluetoothDevice.GetDeviceSelectorFromConnectionStatus(BluetoothConnectionStatus.Connected));
```

For more information, you can see the topic [Enumerate devices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/devices-sensors/enumerate-devices) and the official [DeviceEnumerationAndPairing](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/main/Samples/DeviceEnumerationAndPairing) sample.

Comment: How I can  identify if a device is switched off or not in discoverable range

Comment: This code doesn't work any more. It reports exception: This AQS device filter is not yet supported in Uno Platform. Any idea? @Breeze Liu