# How to get connected Bluetooth device's property in Windows?

Tags: c#, windows, bluetooth

I need to get connected Bluetooth device's property in Windows via C#. And I find this post:

[Getting a list of already connected bluetooth devices on Windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51526156/getting-a-list-of-already-connected-bluetooth-devices-on-windows-10)

The code it mentioned is:

```
//Connected bluetooth devices
DeviceInformationCollection ConnectedBluetoothDevices =
       await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(BluetoothDevice.GetDeviceSelectorFromConnectionStatus(BluetoothConnectionStatus.Connected));
```

But when running the code, I get below exception. It seems that this method cannot be used any more.

Any advise?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might still be usefull.

I got information about connected bluetooth devices using [this package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/32feet.NET) and  following code

```
public class Bluetooth
    {
        public async Task<BluetoothDeviceInfo[]> GetBluetoothDevices()
        {
            var bluetoothClient = new BluetoothClient();
            var devices = await Task.Run(() => bluetoothClient.DiscoverDevices());
            bluetoothClient.Close();
            return devices;
        }
    }

    public static async void SomeAction()
    {
        var bluetooth = new Bluetooth();
        var ConnectedDevices = await bluetooth.GetBluetoothDevices();
        if (ConnectedDevices != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ConnectedDevices[0].DeviceName);
            Console.WriteLine(ConnectedDevices[0].DeviceAddress);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

- The linked answer is almost 5 years old and uses the [Universal Windows Platform (UWP)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/).
- [UWP has been officially deprecated for almost 2 years](https://www.thurrott.com/dev/258377/microsoft-officially-deprecates-uwp) (and eg. [does not support .NET 5 and higher](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2021/10/19/uwp-migration.aspx)).
- Which is why I would not bother trying to get this deprecated approach running (you most probably will run into other problems later - I did when I tried), but look for alternatives instead.
- Eg. [C# Bluetooth example – searching & listing devices in 2023](https://robbelroot.de/blog/csharp-bluetooth-example-searching-listing-devices/) (via [Google "c# bluetooth devices", limited to results from last year](https://www.google.com/search?q=c%23+bluetooth+devices&tbs=qdr:y&biw=1569))

Good luck!

Comment: Yep this should do it. In the case OP doesn't want to read that article here is the github to the Nuget referenced in the article: https://github.com/inthehand/32feet